# Find which numbers were added to produce a result

Tags: php, sql, math

Concrete example :

I have this list of numbers : 1, 2, 4, 8, 16 
and a result : 6

The only possibility to have the result 6 with addition only and using only 2 numbers is to use
4 and 2

Is it possible in mathematics, php or sql to find this two numbers '2' and '4' 
with the result '6' with this list ( 1,2,4,8,16 ) using only 2 numbers?

Thanks for help,
jess

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it looks like homework and provides no working.

Comment: 4+1+1 would also give 6

Comment: hm... but it is interesting. Can you use 2 number only?

Comment: no at all, its a php field selection pb at base..

Comment: But what would you want as a result if your number set was `1,2,3,4` with an answer of `6`

Comment: @PezCuckow, why bother if it's homework or not? It's a great question, just don't comment if you don't know the answer yourself ;)

Comment: I'm quite interested in this also. Hopefully this won't be closed as off topic or something.

Comment: i edited, using only 2 numbers

Comment: Is it possible to have `0` or negative numbers in the list of numbers?

Comment: Is the list of numbers always successive powers of two (1, 2, 4, 8, 16) or can it change?

Comment: its a Branch and bound problem : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound

Comment: You need to return the two numbers that added become 6 or just if the list contains the two numbers that added become 6?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Clearly you're trying to see if bits are on. Consider this code:

```
$bitOn = 6 & 2;
```

the result of that is going to be `true` because the `2` bit is on. From that you can derive a solution where you iterate through the list and compare each value to determine which bits are on.

Here is the documentation on the [PHP Bitwise operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php).

Comment: Good work Michael. I haven't a clue what this is all about and the docs look pretty terrifying, but I'll give it a crack. You've taught me something also. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can get all such pairs using SQL:

```
select l1.num as num1, l2.num as num2
from list l1 join
     list l2
     on l1.num + l2.num = 6 and
        l1.num < l2.num;
```

You can see this on SQL Fiddle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/13640).

Answer (score 1):

Well in sql:

```
SELECT t.number, tt.number
from number_table t, number_table tt
where t.number<>tt.number and t.number+tt.number=@result
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP:

```
$array = explode(",", "1,2,4,8,16");
$result = 6;

foreach($array as $number) {
    foreach($array as $second_number) {
        $sub_result = $number + $second_number;
        if($sub_result === $result) {
            echo "Found match! It's " . $number . "+" . $second_number . "<br />";
        }
    }
}
```

Output looks like:

```
Found match! It's 2+4
Found match! It's 4+2
```